# How to add Exception to route with :any in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

In my project,  have setup an admin panel under a folder inside controllers folder like this

```
controllers/admin_panel/dashboard.php
```

And when we open it like this, it loads `dashboard` controller default
http://www.mysite.com/admin_panel

Now I have added a `page` controller on root level to load the page content from database. So here I have some a setup of kind of CMS. To load the page controller, I have added a condition in routes as below

$route[':any'] = "page";

But what it is doing now is, when I try to open admin_panel, it loads the page controller.
So I want to add a kind of exception condition here like **route any except `admin_panel`**

Any suggestions how can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define another route right above that one that will take you to the admin panel. In CodeIgniter, routes will run in the order they are defined.

```
$route['admin_panel'] = 'admin_panel';
$route[':any'] = 'page';
```

You should be able to access the admin_panel with the above routing.

Comment: I have tried it but then it don't load sub pages under admin_panel like admin_panel/user_manager or admin_panel/user_add

Comment: @aslamdoctor for that you need to add another route before the last one, `$route['admin_panel/(:any)'] = "admin_panel/$1";`

Comment: @DamienPirsy suppose I want to add some checking in page controller like if the controller with he name passed in URL exists exists then load that controller, else look for that page in database. e.g mysite.com/about-us   for this, there is an enrtry in database, so it will load the content for 'about-us' & print it using "page" controller only. but lets say if I already have controller named "about-us" and I want to load that, how can I do that?

Comment: @aslamdoctor I think you should post a question for that, instead of just commenting on an answer.